# QuickSort Three Way Partition + Hybrid Implementation

Tags: java, quicksort, hybrid

I am trying to implement a Three Way Partition QuickSort using a Hybrid QuickSort. The problem is that I am getting an unordered list at the end. I've tested the Hybrid QuickSort and Insertion Sort on their own and they work perfectly (tested for sizes: 10, 50, 500, 1000, 5000). I run debug and can't still tell what the problem is. Thank you in advance. Here is the code.

```
public <T> void sort(@NotNull Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull List<T> list) {
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = list.size() - 1;

    if (hi <= lo) return;
    int lt = lo, i = lo+1, gt = hi;
    while (i <= gt) {
        if (comparator.compare(list.get(i), list.get(lo)) < 0) //did not use AbstractSorter greter in order to check all cases.
            exch(list, lt++, i++);
        else if(comparator.compare(list.get(i), list.get(lo)) > 0)
            exch(list, i, gt--);
        else
            i++;
    }  // Now a[lo..lt-1] < v = a[lt..gt] < a[gt+1..hi].
    sort(comparator, list, lo, lt - 1);
    sort(comparator, list, gt + 1, hi);
}

private <T> void sort(@NotNull Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull List<T> list, int lo, int hi){
    if(hi <= lo) return;
    if(hi - lo <= 8){
        InsertionSort sorter = new InsertionSort();
        sorter.sort(comparator, list.subList(lo, hi + 1));
        List<SorterListener> listeners = (ArrayList)sorter.getListeners();
        for(SorterListener s: listeners)
            getListeners().add(s);
        return;
    }
    int i = partition(comparator, list, lo, hi);
    sort(comparator, list, lo, i - 1);
    sort(comparator, list, i + 1, hi);
}
```

**Edit:**

```
public <T> void exch(@NotNull List<T> list, int i, int j) {
    final T aux = list.get(i);
    list.add(i, list.get(j));
    list.remove(i + 1);
    list.add(j, aux);
    list.remove(j + 1);
    listeners.get(0).swap(i, j);
}


public <T> int partition(@NotNull Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull List<T> list, int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo - 1;
    int j = hi;
    while(true) {
        while( greater(list, hi, ++i, comparator)) //find item left to swap
            if (i == hi) break;
        while( greater(list, --j, hi, comparator)) //find item right to swap
            if (j == lo) break;
        if (i >= j) break; //check if pointers cross
        exch(list, i, j); //swap
    }
    exch(list, i, hi); //swap with partitioning item
    return i; //return index of item now known to be in place
}
```

Comment: It would be OK for me to run your code and see if I stumble on anything. To do that I would need the remaining parts, like InsertionSort, exch() and partition().

Comment: Also in `sort(Comparator<T>, List<T>)`, what is `j`?

Comment: I've found that the problem must be in the first public method, as I tried sorting it with another quick sort using said method and I got the same exact unordered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intent in the partitoning in the first `sort` method (the public one), `lt` points to the element you are partitioning by. So in your comparisons, you should compare the element at `i` with the element at `lt`, not the one at `lo`:

```
    if (comparator.compare(list.get(i), list.get(lt)) < 0) //did not use AbstractSorter greter in order to check all cases.
        exch(list, lt++, i++);
    else if(comparator.compare(list.get(i), list.get(lt)) > 0)
        exch(list, i, gt--);
```

With this change the method seems to work correctly, at least on the samples I have run it on.

BTW, your comment helped me, `Now a[lo..lt-1] < v = a[lt..gt] < a[gt+1..hi].` You can do even better by transforming it into assertions:

```
    T v = list.get(lt);
    for (int ix = lo; ix < lt; ix++) {
        assert comparator.compare(list.get(ix), v) < 0 : "lt " + lt + ' ' + list;
    }
    for (int ix = lt; ix <= gt; ix++) {
        assert comparator.compare(list.get(ix), v) == 0 : "lt " + lt + " gt " + gt + ' ' + list;
    }
    for (int ix = gt + 1; ix <= hi; ix++) {
        assert comparator.compare(list.get(ix), v) > 0 : "gt " + gt + ' ' + list;
    }
```

With these assertion enabled, Java will catch the error and print for instance:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: gt 2 [1, 0, 3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 5, 2, 7, 10]
```

In this case `gt` points to the element `3`, but there’s a `2` further to the right in the list.